# IXFR and inconsistent condensation results

Tags: domain-name-system

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/pdfrfc/rfc1995.txt.pdf says:

> An IXFR server may optionally condense multiple difference sequences
> into a single difference sequence, thus, dropping information on
> intermediate versions.
>
> This may be beneficial if a lot of versions, not all of which are
> useful, are generated. (...).
>
> But, this feature may not be so useful if an IXFR client has access
> to two IXFR servers: A and B, with inconsistent condensation results.
> The current version of the IXFR client, received from server A, may
> be unknown to server B. In such a case, server B can not provide
> incremental data from the unknown version and a full zone transfer is
> necessary.

Could you shed some more light on how such a situation could occur? I mean, how is it even possible that an IXFR client would do IXFRs from two servers as it is primarily - as I understand - used to transfer the "lacking part" of the zone from master authoritative server.

Also, even if the IXFR client sends for some reason IXFRs to two different server, I still don't understand what the problem is about. Can you give some illustrative example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot say for sure what scenario was imagined by the author, but this is my take on it:

Nameserver A has the actual master zone
Nameserver B itself gets the zone via IXFR from A
(One of several options, another would be that A and B both IXFR from C which has the actual master zone.)

Your nameserver is configured to IXFR the zone from A or B

By the same reasoning of how multiple changes can be condensed into one transfer via IXFR, B may not have every single intermediate version available.

If you then IXFR from B, but your current version was received from A, you may currently be at a version that B never saw and B would fall back to full AXFR.